# How to query for posts that are outside of the user's area? (parse.com) (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

Right now in my app, users can post images and it saves the user's current location with the image. In the table view i want it to query for images that are 5-10 km away from the user's area. Also users have their geolocation saved in their profile.

I know there is this code:

```
 query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: usergeo, withinKilometers: limitlocation)
```

but that is within x miles, i want x miles away.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything in Parse's SDK that does this. You'll have to manually calculate a series of geoPoints that are 5 to 10 miles away and use them as your geoPoint values for the nearGeoPoint query.

I may have misunderstood you - do you just want to figure out how far away the geoPoints are from the user? You'll have to manually calculate that too...

Here is a link for determining distance to CLLocations, which you can create from geoPoints: [Calculate distance between two place using latitude-longitude in gmap for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175412/calculate-distance-between-two-place-using-latitude-longitude-in-gmap-for-iphone)

Edit: I forgot that you asked how to do this in swift, not objective-c: [iOS: (Swift) How to show distance from current location and exist annotation on annotation subtitle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069970/ios-swift-how-to-show-distance-from-current-location-and-exist-annotation-on)